# Not able to execute anything that is inside Single.create - rxjava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

Hi I have a function `store` which has a Single.create and at the moment there is just a Timber log message.

code inside the Single.create does not get executed.

```
public Single<String> store(final String filePath, final byte[] fileContents) {

    Timber.d("inside store method");

        Single<String> single = Single.create(subscriber -> {
            Timber.d("Inside single");
        });

        return single.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

This Store function gets called from two places one is from the class where it is living in which works fine, but when I call it from a different class code inside the Single.create does not get executed.

The call which does not work is called from a kotlin class

Any suggestions of why this might be happening?

your help suggestion will be much appreciated.

thanks
R

Edit

Single.create which is rx package

```
   /**
 * Returns a Single that will execute the specified function when a {@link SingleSubscriber} executes it or
 * a {@link Subscriber} subscribes to it.
 * <p>
 * <img width="640" height="200" src="https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/Single.create.png" alt="">
 * <p>
 * Write the function you pass to {@code create} so that it behaves as a Single: It should invoke the
 * SingleSubscriber {@link SingleSubscriber#onSuccess onSuccess} and/or
 * {@link SingleSubscriber#onError onError} methods appropriately.
 * <p>
 * A well-formed Single must invoke either the SingleSubscriber's {@code onSuccess} method exactly once or
 * its {@code onError} method exactly once.
 * <p>
 * <dl>
 * <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 * <dd>{@code create} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param <T>
 *            the type of the item that this Single emits
 * @param f
 *            a function that accepts an {@code SingleSubscriber<T>}, and invokes its {@code onSuccess} or
 *            {@code onError} methods as appropriate
 * @return a Single that, when a {@link Subscriber} subscribes to it, will execute the specified function
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: Create</a>
 */
public static <T> Single<T> create(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
    return new Single<T>(f);
}
```

This is how I call from kotlin

```
 val result = pdfTicketStorage.store(offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketFilePath, offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketContent)
        Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - postPrintedTicket - result - " + result )
```

Comment: Please post the code for Single.create too. As you pass a lambda function, it's likely that this lambda function never gets called inside Single.create().

Comment: Hello @JayC667 i have updated the question with the Single.create which is in rx package

Comment: How are you calling it from Kotlin? Usually there are two mistakes to look for: using curly braces instead of parenthesis; log coalescing hides the fact the code did run but the log message got removed.

Comment: hello @akarnokd this is how I am calling from kotlin
 val result = pdfTicketStorage.store(offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketFilePath, offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketContent)
        Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - postPrintedTicket - result - " + result )

Comment: Where do you call `subscribe()`?

Comment: that is the only thing I did to call that method. I am new to this, can you suggest how should I be calling it from Kotlin function please

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#getting-started

Comment: @akarnokd okay will do that. so if I just subscribe like this it should be fine?
val result = pdfTicketStorage.store(offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketFilePath, offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketContent).subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

> You forgot to call subscribe method

Rx will start execute your code when you call subscribe method also make sure to handle on error method as well.

```
pdfTicketStorage.store(offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketFilePath, offlinePrintedTicketInfo.pdfTicketContent)
 .subscribe(
    { 
       result ->
         //here is your result 
     }, 
    {
       error ->
         //this is when file not found or eny error thrown
     })
```